# Inserting AdSense code right after </head> tag

Tags: adsense

i would like to to add an AdSense activation code to my Wordpress site.

Google says it needs to be inserted right AFTER the  tag

I have tried the plugin Snippets, yet it seems not to be working.

The code is:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script> 
<script>   
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push(
{     google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5316020100281676",
enable_page_level_ads: true   }); 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you view the page source, where are you seeing the code getting inserted? On Chrome, right click > View Page Source

Comment: It does not actually show anywhere. I tried inserting it as a widget to a siderbar, yet it creates a new paragraph and messes up the graphic.

The official Google Adsense plugin does not seem to work.

Comment: I've suggested an answer on how to add this without using a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Without using a plugin, the WordPress way would be to use the `wp_head` action to insert the script and then enqueue the script file:

```
function mytextdomain_adsense() {
    $output="
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({ 
        google_ad_client: 'ca-pub-5316020100281676',
        enable_page_level_ads: true   
      });
    </script>";

    echo $output;
}
add_action('wp_head','mytextdomain_adsense');

function mytextdomain_adense_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-adsense', '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytextdomain_adense_script' );
```

And to add the `async` attribute to the script link:

```
function mytextdomain_add_async_attribute($tag, $handle) {
    if ( 'my-adsense' !== $handle ) {
      return $tag;
    }
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'mytextdomain_add_async_attribute', 10, 2);
```

This should be placed in the theme's `functions.php` file (preferably a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so that it doesn't get overwritten if there's a theme update).

Comment: This will insert the code before the `</head>` and not after as required in the question. Not sure if there are any practical differences. The bigger problem is that the script code should depend on the inclusion of the library and come after it, which can be done with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/. But the biggest problem is that with this code the library is not included as `async` resource, and that is a major problem

Comment: Fair point about it loading before `</head>` but I don't see how this will affect the script's functionality. By enqueuing the link and loading it in the header (that's what the `false` bit is for), it will load in the correct order. As for `async`, also a good observation. I had actually missed that. I'll update my answer to account for it.

Comment: it will most likely end up in the right order due to enque having a high priority (1 IIRC), but probably better to have the dependency explicit (I think the order actually do not matter, which is why it can be async at all, but if there is a need to get support from some pedant guy he might say that the problem is with the order, or not having them one right after the other).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if it matter, but Google says it needs to be inserted right AFTER the head. I am having trouble with authorization, so it might be a problem.

It is being inserted into the <head> + the code looks a little bit different than the one Google gave me. For example starting with this line


`<meta name="google-site-verification" content="CC8Q0egOv5QW8aIj-cSK4QZKuCJYWBu3f8xCu1_Ex9Y" />`

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things. Are you trying to do a Google site verification or Adsense? There's no mention of adding a `meta` tag in your original question.

Comment: I want to at AdSense ad to my site, yet Google says it needs to verify my site – telling me to add the code right after my </head> tag.

Comment: You should probably update your question so that it's clear you need to add your Google Site Verification meta link _and also_ the Adsense code.

Comment: Try using the Google Site Verification plugin to complete that step: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-verification-using-meta-tag/ And then add the code in the answer to the `functions.php` file in your theme.

Comment: Oh well, the Google master says the site is "verified", yet the Adsense says it is not.. I guess it's 2 things: some kind of HTML verification and Adsense verification

[screenshot––>](http://imgur.com/nSCizfB)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51163/discussion-between-jan-cervenka-and-jami-gibbs).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they changed their requirements? Google says it needs to be inserted BETWEEN the  tags. See here:

[image: Implementing code into WordPress page (Google manual (GER)]

There are two ways to realize it:

- Use a plugin to paste code into  section.
- Or do it manually: create copy of header.php and save it securely. Then open header.php in a text editor and paste AdSense code just BEFORE closing  tag.